# Have external testers been removed from iTunes Connect / Apple Testflight?

Tags: testflight

I've been looking into using Apple's Testflight in iTunes Connect this morning. About 20 mins ago all references to external testing disappeared. At the same time I got an email from Apple about scheduled maintenance on iTunes connect that's happening in 10 days.

Have they removed the external testers feature for now?

How can I access this feature now?

Comment: This is off-topic because it is about Apple's testing process, not programming.

Comment: Is there a more appropriate forum for this topic?

Comment: @MikeW I've looked into other stack exchange sites and this one is the best fit. My question is about "software tools commonly used by programmers" and is "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development" - http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I honestly have no idea where it went @Jake. I'm in the same boat, I had a beta build "In review" and now that "External Testers" tab disappeared and there is no review status.

Comment: Someone pointed out that the link is just hidden with css. When I remove the `ng-hide` class the link shows but it redirects me to be *builds* page, not *external testers*.

Comment: @Jake I've raised a question on [meta] about this [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276148/1864610)

Comment: Thanks @MikeW I'll join the discussion there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what its worth, looking at in in firebug, the column for External Testers was hidden with CSS.

Update: Its back up and available for me now.

Comment: Yep, back for me too!
Lets hope Apple's making improvements, there are a lot needed in this system.

Comment: yeah...what chaffed my ass is there was no message about them hiding for maintenance or whatever, and given all the crap that can go wrong on app submission (using private APIs, server timeouts, etc,etc), it very much seemed like you (or I) goofed the pooch on something. Which was very frustrating.

Comment: Its just got replaced by "Add Group" which happens after successfully adding your first one.(according to their html if-condition from the inspector)